# How to apply a function of multiple variable to multiple lists

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, iterators

Im new to mathematica ( from a python background) so apologies if this is easy.

I have four lists of equal length from a data set. I would like to iterate through each of the lists and apply a function, then return the values to a list. I have come across the Do command but can't seem to figure it out for multiple variables.

Is there a way to use this or a better way.

```
a_1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
a_2 = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
a_3 = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
a_4 = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}

z1[x_,y_,z_,k_] = A*x + B*y + C*z + D*k
```

I am trying to get an output equivalent to this:

```
 result =  {z1[1,2,10,2], z1[2,3,10,4], z1[3,4,11,6] ...}
```

What is the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: They are not the same length, but take a look at `MapThread`.

Comment: Just a hint: don't use underline (`_`) on your variable names. Unlike in many other languages, it has a special meaning (`Blank`, which is used on pattern matching.)

Comment: Make sure the lists have the same length (your a_3 has 11 elements, not 10). Rename `a_i` into `ai` and then run `z1 @@@ Transpose@{a1, a2, a3, a4}`

Comment: Also it should probably be `z1[x_,y_,z_,k_] := A*x...` the `:` is important

Comment: Note that both `C` and `D` are reserved symbols in *Mathematica*. Good practice in *Mathematica* is to never use capitalized words/symbols for user-defined variables/functions. In this case, use `a, b, c, d` instead of `A, B, C, D`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions (from comments and alternatives).

If we define your lists as

```
a[1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
a[2] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} 
a[3] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20} 
a[4] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}
```

and your function as

```
z1[x_, y_, z_, k_] := b*x + c*y + d*z + e*k
```

(so as not to conflict with the the symbol `a` associated with your lists), you can do:

> BlackKow

```
z1 @@@ Transpose@{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}
z1 @@@ Transpose@Array[a, 4]
(* {b + 2 c + 11 d + 2 e, 2 b + 3 c + 12 d + 4 e, 3 b + 4 c + 13 d + 6 e,
    4 b + 5 c + 14 d + 8 e, 5 b + 6 c + 15 d + 10 e, 6 b + 7 c + 16 d + 12 e,
    7 b + 8 c + 17 d + 14 e, 8 b + 9 c + 18 d + 16 e, 9 b + 10 c + 19 d + 18 e,
    10 b + 11 c + 20 d + 20 e} *)
```

> Kuba

```
MapThread[z1, Array[lst, 4]]
```

Using `Table`:

```
Table[z1[lst[1][[j]], lst[2][[j]], lst[3][[j]], lst[4][[j]]], {j, 1, Length@lst[1]}]
```